# I want to update a field ONLY if it references a specific ROW of other table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 3 tables, "cars", "elements" and "element_status" (for example). I'm NOT able to modify the SQL structure. Here's the code:

```
CREATE TABLE cars(
    idCar VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_cars_idCar PRIMARY KEY (idCar));


CREATE TABLE elements(
    idElement VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    idCar VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT FK_elements_idCar FOREIGN KEY (idCar) REFERENCES cars(idCar),
    CONSTRAINT PK_elements_idElement_idCar PRIMARY KEY (idElement, idCar));


CREATE TABLE element_status(
    idElement VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    status BOOLEAN NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT FK_status_idelement FOREIGN KEY (idElement) REFERENCES elements(idelement),
    CONSTRAINT PK_status_idElement PRIMARY KEY (idElement));
```

So, here's the plot. Each element has a row in element_status. Each element_status row references one element and that element references one car.

So I have a row in "element_status" with idElement="engine" and status=FALSE. This engine references an engine in "elements" with, let's say, idCar="car_1234". But there a lot of engines there, each one pointing to it's car.

I need to update the status to TRUE in "element_status" of the engine with idCar="car_1234" and I need help with it. My mind says it should be easy, (subquery I guess) but actually i don't know how to do it.

Thanks!!

Comment: No subquery required. Just a join the tables and use a `WHERE` clause that matches the specific car you want. There are many SO questions that show how to do an update with a join.

Comment: Thanks!! Always so helpful (:

Comment: Anyway, if someone could put the code I'll be really grateful cause I'm a newbie in SQL.

Comment: Answers can't be posted to closed questions.

Comment: I solved it this way:

UPDATE element_status
SET status=1 
WHERE idElement= (SELECT idElementFROM elements WHERE idCar='thecaricant' AND idElement='lementiwant');

Thank you all

Comment: That will work when there's just one `idElement` being selected. The more general solution is to use a `JOIN`, as in the duplicate question.